# How do I stop a chart from showing on R markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

**Aims**

1. I have got the ouput that I want i.e. an interactive tree map. Yet, the R Markdown output also shows the static tree map, which I do not want to include.
2. I also want to adjust the font size on the interactive chart. I know how to adjust the font sizes of the labels in the static diagram using "fontsize.labels", but this does not affect the interactive tree map.

**Reprex**

````
    ---
    title: "Untitled"
    date: "03/05/2021"
    output: html_document
    ---
    
    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
    ```


    ```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
    library(treemap)
    library(d3treeR)
     
    # dataset
    group <- c(rep("group-1",4),rep("group-2",2),rep("group-3",3))
    subgroup <- paste("subgroup" , c(1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3), sep="-")
    value <- c(13,5,22,12,11,7,3,1,23)
    data <- data.frame(group,subgroup,value)
     
    # basic treemap
    p <- treemap(data,
                index=c("group","subgroup"),
                vSize="value",
                type="index",
                palette = "Set2",
                bg.labels=c("white"),
                align.labels=list(
                  c("center", "center"), 
                  c("right", "bottom")
                )  
              )            
     
    # make it interactive ("rootname" becomes the title of the plot):
    inter <- d3tree2( p ,  rootname = "General" )
    inter
````

**Output**

How do I get rid of the top static tree map?
How do I increase the font size in the interactive tree map?

If you can only answer one of the questions, please do.

[image]

Comment: For Q1: several functions for plotting that also return a structure have a built-in mechanism for disabling the plot itself. In some, it's `plot=`. In others, including here (according to `?treemap`), you should be able to do `p <- treemap(.., draw=FALSE)`. (I know nothing of the function, so cannot comment on Q2.)

Comment: You would add `include = FALSE` To your R chunk to not not have the chart show up, and you can put the 2nd chart in its own R chunk with different chunk options to give it different viewing options